# Cliver and PhantomJS error with update to MacOS Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rspec, phantomjs

I updated from OSX El Capitan to MacOS Sierra and began seeing PhantomJS errors.

`$ rspec <some feature test`
`... The detector #<struct Cliver::Detector command_arg=nil, version_pattern=nil> failed to detect theversion of the executable at '/app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs'`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some playing around, I realized that `$ phantomjs --version` was not returning anything. Strange. I also checked both

```
$ brew list
$ npm ls
```

and saw that neither listed phantomjs as one of their packages. Looks like I had an issue with my phantomjs install. I decided to do a completely fresh install of phantomjs.

I began by determining where phantomjs is installed:

```
$ which phantomjs
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

Remove it:

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
$ phantomjs -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs: No such file or directory
```

Good. Now install phantomjs with npm:

```
$ npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt
$ phantomjs -v
2.1.1
```

This looks promising. Lets run our spec again:

```
$ rspec <some feature test>
1 example, 0 failures
```

Success.

Comment: very useful after an update to the new OS it was crashing too, fixed it right away.